# How to get samples in "bins" from D-Wave's dimod?

Tags: simulation, d-wave

at [1](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/latest/examples/and.html), the following code example is available:

```
>>> from dwave.system.samplers import DWaveSampler
>>> from dwave.system.composites import EmbeddingComposite
>>> sampler = DWaveSampler(endpoint='https://URL_to_my_D-Wave_system/', token='ABC-123456789012345678901234567890', solver='My_D-Wave_Solver')
>>> sampler_embedded = EmbeddingComposite(sampler)
>>> Q = {('x1', 'x2'): 1, ('x1', 'z'): -2, ('x2', 'z'): -2, ('z', 'z'): 3}
>>> response = sampler_embedded.sample_qubo(Q, num_reads=5000)
```

When looking at the results, they are grouped by sample solution, with a mention of the number of occurrences:

```
    >>> for datum in response.data(['sample', 'energy', 'num_occurrences']):   
...    print(datum.sample, "Energy: ", datum.energy, "Occurrences: ", datum.num_occurrences)
...
{'x1': 1, 'x2': 0, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  1009
{'x1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'z': 1} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  1452
{'x1': 0, 'x2': 0, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  1292
{'x1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  1246
{'x1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  1
```

After looking at the available samplers at [2](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/latest/overview/stack.html), I changed the code to simulate the process with D-Wave's Dimod, and repeated this D-Wave's neal:

```
from dwave.system.samplers import DWaveSampler
from dwave.system.composites import EmbeddingComposite
import dimod
import neal
#sampler = DWaveSampler(endpoint='https://URL_to_my_D-Wave_system/',  token='ABC-123456789012345678901234567890', solver='My_D-Wave_Solver')
sampler = dimod.SimulatedAnnealingSampler()
# Note: also tried with neal: 
# sampler = neal.SimulatedAnnealingSampler()
#sampler_embedded = EmbeddingComposite(sampler)
Q = {('x1', 'x2'): 1, ('x1', 'z'): -2, ('x2', 'z'): -2, ('z', 'z'): 3}
#response = sampler_embedded.sample_qubo(Q, num_reads=5000)
response = sampler.sample_qubo(Q, num_reads=500)
```

However, my results are not binned:

```
for datum in response.data(['sample', 'energy', 'num_occurrences']):   
    print(datum.sample, "Energy: ", datum.energy, "Occurrences: ", datum.num_occurrences)    
({'x2': 0, 'x1': 0, 'z': 0}, 'Energy: ', 0.0, 'Occurrences: ', 1)
({'x2': 1, 'x1': 1, 'z': 1}, 'Energy: ', 0.0, 'Occurrences: ', 1)
({'x2': 1, 'x1': 1, 'z': 1}, 'Energy: ', 0.0, 'Occurrences: ', 1)
[497 similar lines removed]
```

My question: how can I make sure my results are correctly binned*? 
OR: how should I properly port the given code to be able to simulate it without access to the actual D-Wave hardware?

*: I am not asking for a generic algorithm to create bins/histograms, I have those already. I am looking for a function of set of parameters from the D-Wave libraries, as I'm surprised by the different outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old answer :
Maybe the answer mode differs using a different sampler. I have not tried but I know there is an option "answer_mode" in the sample_qubo method. If answer_mode='raw', you will have all responses not binned. If answer_mode='histogram', you should get them as bins.

New answer : 
Dimod does not use the answer_mode argument. To work it in your way, 
you have to aggregate response:

```
Q = {('x1', 'x2'): 1, ('x1', 'z'): -2, ('x2', 'z'): -2, ('z', 'z'): 3}

response = sampler.sample_qubo(Q, num_reads=500)
response = response.aggregate()
```

Then you will have bins :

```
for datum in response.data(['sample', 'energy', 'num_occurrences']):   
    print(datum.sample, "Energy: ", datum.energy, "Occurrences: ", datum.num_occurrences)
```

This yields for me :

{'x1': 0, 'x2': 1, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  134

{'x1': 1, 'x2': 1, 'z': 1} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  123

{'x1': 0, 'x2': 0, 'z': 0} Energy:  0.0 Occurrences:  115
...

Comment: I think this is in the right direction, but not yet there. 
sampler = dimod.SimulatedAnnealingSampler(answer_mode='histogram') returned unexpected keyword argument, even though I can find it here: https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/c_solver_1.html.

Comment: @ThomasHubregtsen Try sampler.sample_qubo(Q, num_reads=500, answer_mode='histogram')

Comment: also tried this one, did not work either:
TypeError: sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'answer_mode'

Comment: Seems like in dimod, things are done differentl (see examples similar to yours https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/latest/overview/solving_problems.html)

Comment: @ThomasHubregtsen Found the trick by looking in the dimod repository

Comment: answer_mode='histogram'  was in the right direction, but response.aggregate() did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As cnada pointed out, the correct parameter for this is "answer_mode". This parameter is not available for the simulated_annealing sampler.

As per [1](https://dwave-systemdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/samplers/generated/dwave.system.samplers.DWaveSampler.sample_qubo.html), samplers.DWaveSampler.sample_qubo() can take the set of parameters mentioned in [2](https://dwave-systemdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/samplers/generated/dwave.system.samplers.DWaveSampler.parameters.html#dwave.system.samplers.DWaveSampler.parameters), including "answer mode". As seen in [3](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dimod/en/latest/reference/generated/dimod.reference.samplers.simulated_annealing.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.sample_qubo.html#dimod.reference.samplers.simulated_annealing.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.sample_qubo), samplers.simulated_annealing.sample_qubo() can only take beta_range’, num_reads’, ‘num_sweeps’ [4](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dimod/en/latest/reference/generated/dimod.reference.samplers.simulated_annealing.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.parameters.html#dimod.reference.samplers.simulated_annealing.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.parameters). This does not include "answer_mode".